# Can you still use API Youtube V2?

Tags: javascript, youtube, jsonp

I am learning Jquery mobile, and trying to retrieve Youtube videos from a channel. I am following the instructions for the course, and get back response from Youtube but no arrays with videos.
 I saw that the google API Youtube webpage have market API youtube V2 as "Deprecated". Does that mean that I need to register every app for getting videos from Youtube with V3, or can I still use the API V2? Why I am not getting any array in the console?

```
<script src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/drumeo/uploads?alt=json-in-script&max-results=30&callback=listVideos" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in JavaScript:

```
function listVideos(data){
console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: It seems you are missing a closing `</script>` tag. It works fine with it: http://jsfiddle.net/t6qvC//

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it, but not missing in my editor :(. Updated the code, thanks.

Comment: Well, as you can see in my jsFiddle, the code by itself works. So the problem must be in the rest of your code. Make sure `listVideos` is defined when the other script element is executed.

Comment: Hi Felix, can I get the link from your jsFiddel? I get in return the object, but if you navigate in the console, seems that the arrays with the videos is missing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t6qvC/ (somehow the link above was broken). You are right, there doesn't seem to be any links to videos in the response. But that might be because the users didn't upload any videos: http://www.youtube.com/user/drumeo/videos

Comment: Hey. Well, i figured out. The link that worked is the following:

`<script src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=drumeo&v=2&max-results=20&alt=jsonc&callback=listVideos"type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Because that's the user you want to get the videos from: `http://www.youtube.com/user/freedrumlessons`. So, `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/freedrumlessons/uploads?alt=json-in-script&max-results=30&callback=listVideos` works fine as well.